# How to hold on pylab.semilogy figures?

Tags: python, python-2.7, graph, matplotlib

How to hold on two figures of semilogy graphics of pylab? I've tried with pylab.hold(True) but it open two different windows, for two calls to my graphics function (i need the graphics in just one window). Here the code:

edit1 - here's more complete code, and the correction of name uses:

```
(import pylab as pl)
```

edit 2: i need to hold on the grafics of two consecutive calls to graphics function:
call to graphics in the module:

```
graphics(pet, SNR_dB)
graphics(another_pet, SNR_dB)
```

whit a pl.array and a list (with the same dimention), for example:
(Generated whit arange(0,18))

```
SNR_dB:  [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17]
```

And the Pe, generated with another calcules in the script:

```
Pe:  [0.29576000000000002, 0.24626000000000001, 0.19703999999999999, 0.15298, 0.11018, 0.074139999999999998, 0.04616, 0.024400000000000002, 0.01204, 0.0050000000000000001, 0.0018600000000000001, 0.00040000000000000002, 4.0000000000000003e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
[0.16062000000000001, 0.13156000000000001, 0.10384, 0.079699999999999993, 0.056710000000000003, 0.037859999999999998, 0.023400000000000001, 0.01222, 0.0060400000000000002, 0.0025000000000000001, 0.00093000000000000005, 0.00020000000000000001, 2.0000000000000002e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

The graphics function is:

```
def graphics(Pe, SNR_dB):

    pl.semilogy(SNR_dB, Pe[0],linewidth=1)
    pl.hold(True)
    pl.semilogy(SNR_dB, Pe[1],linewidth=2)
    pl.legend(('Symbol', 'bit'))

    pl.xlim([0, max(SNR_dB)])
    pl.ylim([1e-10,1])

    pl.title('Error vs SNR_dB')
    pl.grid(True)
    pl.xlabel('SNR_dB')
    pl.ylabel('Pe')
    pl.show()
```

This two calls to "graphics" generates two figures, one for each call. I need that in just one figure. How i do?

Comment: Can you expand on your problem and explain it a bit more? If I use your code with some generated data then I get a sensible semilog plot with both plots on the same plot (as you seem to want). In fact you don't even need to call `pl.hold(True)` to get them both on the same plot.

Comment: Note that as your code currently stands you will get a NameError as you are using `pylab.show()` rather than `pl.show()`. Was this a mistake when you copied it into the Stack Overflow window or does fixing this fix your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

whith this edits (i dont use figure or show until the two calls to graphics)

```
graphics(pet, SNR_dB)
graphics(another_pet, SNR_dB)
pl.show()

def graphics(Pe, SNR_dB):

    pl.semilogy(SNR_dB, Pe[0],linewidth=1)
    pl.semilogy(SNR_dB, Pe[1],linewidth=2)
    pl.legend(('Symbol', 'bit'))

    pl.xlim([0, max(SNR_dB)])
    pl.ylim([1e-10,1])

    pl.title('Error vs SNR_dB')
    pl.grid(True)
    pl.xlabel('SNR_dB')
    pl.ylabel('Pe')
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `pylab` *at all costs* (only half-exaggerating)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(SNR_dB, Pe_list[0],linewidth=1)
ax.plot(SNR_dB, Pe_list[1],linewidth=2)
ax.legend(('Symbol', 'bit'))

ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xlim([0, max(SNR_dB)])
ax.set_ylim([1e-10,1])

ax.set_title('Error vs SNR_dB')
ax.set_xlabel('SNR_dB')
ax.set_ylabel('Pe')

ax.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I need to solve with pylab. It's the module that im using in the script.

Comment: @eduardo.sufan `pylab` is a module of `matplotlib`. in other words, `pylab` and `pyplot` are two different interfaces to the *same* library.